# Does a dump before store creates a separate job?

Tags: apache-pig

Pig generates so much output that I find it hard to figure out what it is actually doing.

E.g., if I do `dump foo;` before `store foo ...;` - does it generate an extra MR job for the `dump` or does it piggyback on the following `store` job?

(the data set in question is small -- ~100 records)

Comment: There is a related topic for using multiple STOREs: http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/perf.html#multi-query-execution I don't know how STORE and DUMP interact together though.

Comment: @Ruslan: thanks! the link answers the question!

Answer (score 1):

[multi-query-execution](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/perf.html#multi-query-execution):

> You do not want to use DUMP as it will disable multi-query execution
>   and is likely to slow down execution. (If you have included DUMP
>   statements in your scripts for debugging purposes, you should remove
>   them.)